# Qt - Display Designer Form without class

Tags: forms, qt, designer

In Qt, I have created a Designer Form without class. So basically, I just have a file myform.ui. What code should I write to display the form?

Comment: For displaying a .ui file, in _Design_ mode go to: _Tools > Form Editor > Preview (Alt+Shift+R)_. You can also add some widgets to the form and then display it again. But it's only a preview!

Answer (score 6):

If you include(d) the ui file in the .pro in the `FORMS` section, a special header file will be generated during build process. Include this header file and use it to add the child widgets to any QWidget you want during runtime.

The ui file in this example is called **mywidget.ui**. In your .pro file, there is a line saying

```
FORMS += mywidget.ui
```

QtCreator will show the file in the project explorer. This step is important because otherwise no header file will be generated when building your project!

The generated header file is then called **ui_mywidget.h** and the class to compose the designed window is called `Ui::MyWidget` and can be used as follows.

**Solution 1** (the way QtCreator suggests when you create a new "*Qt Designer Form Class*"):

```
namespace Ui {
class MyWidget;
}

class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MyWidget();

private:
    Ui::MyWidget *ui;     // Pointer to the UI class where the child widgets are
};
```

```
#include "ui_mywidget.h"
MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MyWidget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);    // Create and add the child widgets to this widget
}

MyWidget::~MyWidget()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Then this widget is ready to use and will contain the child widgets you created in the designer whenever instantiating it:

```
MyWidget widget;
widget.show();
```

**Solution 2** (without inheriting from QWidget):

```
#include "ui_mywidget.h"
...
QWidget *widget = new QWidget(...);
Ui::MyWidget ui;         // Instance of the UI class where the child widgets are
ui.setupUi(widget);      // Create and add the child widgets to this widget
widget->show();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [QUiLoader](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/quiloader.html) to load the ui file.

Answer (score 0):

The official way to use ui files is explained [here](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html).

As you can see, you have two options: "process ui files at compile time" or "at runtime".

About compile time processing, you have three other sub cases: "Direct Approach" (the classic way, adopted when you create a new "Qt Designer Form Class"), and the "Single Inheritance" / "Multiple Inheritance Approach". In the mentioned article you will find all the details.